# PHP: Read file from line X to line Y?

Tags: php, arrays

This code will read lines from 1000 to 2000 then save to array. However, when I run it, it shows nothing. Please help me fix it ! Thank you !

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$filename = glob(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.txt');
$file = new SplFileObject($filename[0]);
$fileIterator = new LimitIterator($file, 1000, 2000);
foreach($fileIterator as $line) {
    $array=$line, PHP_EOL;
}
var_dump($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
$array=$line, PHP_EOL;
```

to this:

```
$array[]=$line . PHP_EOL;
```